# Deleting ALL cookies from a subdomain

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, cookies, subdomain

I created a CNAME subdomain called static that's pointing to www.mywebsite.com.

I created also a virtual host with the same name with root /website.com
I have these cookies on the page static.website.com

[image: LOCAL COOKIES]
[image: THIRD PART]

How can I get rid of them?

I tried to add an .htacces inside the STATIC folder with this code but it's not working

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$">
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Nope, you can only do that from the other subdomain.

Comment: if you are executing the code on one.yourserver.comand you want to delete a cookie on two.yourserver.com. Nope, you can only do that from the other subdomain.

Comment: but the other subdomain is the folder STATIC I can see in my FTP right?